# How to implement CheckBox in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here I have mentioned my code of checkbox. I am new to flutter, So I have to implement it for Remember me functionality.

**Code:**

```
 Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
     new Checkbox(value: checkBoxValue,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          onChanged:(bool newValue){
        setState(() {
          checkBoxValue = newValue;
        });
       Text('Remember me');
          }),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: So what is your problem or your question?

Comment: My problem is basically i wanna implement the "remember me" feature of  my credentials username, and password using checkBox in flutter.

Answer (score 102):

If you need a `Checkbox` with a label then you can use a `CheckboxListTile`:

```dart
CheckboxListTile(
  title: Text("title text"),
  value: checkedValue,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      checkedValue = newValue;
    });
  },
  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,  //  <-- leading Checkbox
)
```

Comment: the request is for a checkbox not a checkbox list tile.....

Comment: How can I add gradient color to checkbox?

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but if it was how to bind functionality to the `Checkbox`, this `State` of a `StatefulWidget` should serve as a minimal working example for you:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool rememberMe = false;

  void _onRememberMeChanged(bool newValue) => setState(() {
    rememberMe = newValue;

    if (rememberMe) {
      // TODO: Here goes your functionality that remembers the user.
    } else {
      // TODO: Forget the user
    }
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: rememberMe,
      onChanged: _onRememberMeChanged
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

U try that code it work perfect

> **Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'checkbox_in_listview_task-7.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   // This widget is the root of your application.   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      home: CheckBoxInListview(),
    );   } }
```

> **checkbox_in_listview_task-7.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GetCheckValue extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  GetCheckValueState createState() {
    return new GetCheckValueState();
  }
}

class GetCheckValueState extends State<GetCheckValue> {
  bool _isChecked = true;
  String _currText = '';

  List<String> text = ["InduceSmile.com", "Flutter.io", "google.com"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Get check Value Example"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(_currText,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            height: 350.0,
            child: Column(
              children: text
                  .map((t) => CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text(t),
                        value: _isChecked,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            _isChecked = val;
                            if (val == true) {
                              _currText = t;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It give you outPut something like that

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox in flutter is a material design widget. It is always used in the Stateful Widget as it does not maintain a state of its own. We can use its onChanged property to interact or modify other widgets in the flutter app. Like most of the other flutter widgets, it also comes with many properties like activeColor, checkColor, mouseCursor, etc, to let developers have full control over the widget's look and feel.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//importing material design liverary
void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
    //runApp method
    home: HomePage(),
));//MaterialApp
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
bool value = false;

@override
//App widget tree
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GeeksforGeeks'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[400],
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            tooltip: 'Menu',
            onPressed: () {},
        ), //IcoButton
        ), //AppBar
        body: Center(
        /** Card Widget **/
        child: Card(
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 430,
                height: 700,
                child: Column(
                children: [
                    Text(
                    'Algorithms',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.greenAccent[400],
                        fontSize: 30), //TextStyle
                    ), //Text
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                        ), //SizedBox
                        Text(
                        'Library Implementation Of Searching Algorithm: ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                        ), //Text
                        SizedBox(width: 10), //SizedBox
                        /** Checkbox Widget **/
                        Checkbox(
                        value: this.value,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                            setState(() {
                            this.value = value;
                            });
                        },
                        ), //Checkbox
                    ], //<Widget>[]
                    ), //Row
                ],
                ), //Column
            ), //SizedBox
            ), //Padding
        ), //Card
        ), //Center//Center
    ), //Scaffold
    ); //MaterialApp
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Implementing checkbox without reloading the whole UI on setState

I think many answers missed the fact that the checkbox will update the whole UI on setState which is most likely what we don't want. To avoid this either 1/ use [provider or riverpod package](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) or 2/ encapsulate the checkbox into another stateful widget with a callback, see following example:

In the parent class:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  ...
  CheckboxWidget(callback: (value) => _rememberPassword = value),
  ...

 }

...
```

Along with the following child widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckboxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool) callback;

  const CheckboxWidget({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CheckboxWidgetState createState() => _CheckboxWidgetState();
}

class _CheckboxWidgetState extends State<CheckboxWidget> {
  bool _checkbox = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return   CheckboxListTile(
      title: const Text('Remember Password', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
      value: _checkbox,
      onChanged: (value) {
        widget.callback(value!);
        setState(() => _checkbox = !_checkbox);},
    );
  }
}
```