# checkbox in flutter not change

Tags: flutter

```
Checkbox(
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isHighBloodDisease = value;
                    });
                  },
                  value: isHighBloodDisease,
                ),
```

this is my code and when i click the checkbox the check is not apper but when i close the dropDownList and reopen it the box i have choice is checked and I tryed to print the value and it works when i click it print true

```
return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: 350,
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        iconSize: 50,
        iconEnabledColor: white,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'الامراض المزمنة',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: white),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: white,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  chronicDisease[0]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle,
                ),
                Checkbox(
                  value: isHeartDisease,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isHeartDisease = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  chronicDisease[4]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle,
                ),
                Checkbox(
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isHighBloodDisease = value;
                    });
                  },
                  value: isHighBloodDisease,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ].toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `dropDownList`'s code?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323734/8150077

Comment: @Jhakiz i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To respond to your comment:

> i have another prob I am developing an arabic app so i want the arrow of the dropDown in the next side how can I change the alignment?

Wrap `DropdownButtonFormField` with `Directionality` widget:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 50,
    width: 350,
        child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                 iconSize: 50,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'الامراض المزمنة',
```

For more info take a look to this question:
[right-to-left (RTL) in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter)

Comment: this was ssoo helpful I tried to wrap it with another widget but it didn’t work , I didn’t hear about directionality widget before. However thankss alot

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet code:

> Create a statefullwidget for checkboxes:

```
class CheckboxSelectorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isChecked = false;

  CheckboxSelectorPage(this.isChecked, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CheckboxSelectorPageState createState() => _CheckboxSelectorPageState();
}

class _CheckboxSelectorPageState extends State<CheckboxSelectorPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        widget.isChecked = value;
        print("value: $value Is mounted: $mounted");
        setState(() {
          widget.isChecked = value;
        });
      },
      value: widget.isChecked,
    );
  }
}
```

> Replace `Checkbox` widget by:

```
 CheckboxSelectorPage(),
```

This example has been tested in **dartpad.dev**

Comment: i have another prob I am developing an arabic app so i want the arrow of the dropDown in the next side how can I change the alignment?

Comment: If it works you can mark it as accepted answer!